# Day by day summing of values from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that gathers data and the table is this structure

```
 Date - Y-m-d H:i:s
 Name - Example
 Quantity - 1

Example
 ID - Date - Name - Quantity
 1 - 2015-05-13 16:33:09 - Test1 - 1
 2 - 2015-05-13 19:10:45 - Test2 - 3
 3 - 2015-05-13 22:01:39 - Test3 - 1
 4 - 2015-05-14 07:13:20 - Test4 - 1
 5 - 2015-05-14 09:29:37 - Test5 - 2
```

How can I add the Quantity on the same date 2015-05-13 by day by day to output the data in this text format: 5, 3 ......

```
require_once 'config.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $db_user, $db_password, $database);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, date, quantity FROM downloads";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["quantity"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Thanks I changed it now. clearly a mistake sorry

Comment: can you show us what youve tried?

Comment: is not understandable what you want.

Comment: I'm not that good at php, I'm more on designing stuff. It's simple code for php experts but a start for me. The code is a simple one just the connection to the database and echo the data

Comment: data gathered from where? Edit: ah, db.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that too, from a mysql database

Comment: Is that a MySQL question actually? Do you need a query that gives you want you ask for?

Comment: you can use MySQL's aggregate functions http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx  some being `SUM()` and `COUNT()` if you want to do math stuff.

Comment: To be honest I'm not really sure how to do it

Comment: Read about [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) and [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query to get the sum of quantities per date

```
SELECT DATE(`Date`), SUM(quantity) FROM downloads GROUP BY DATE(`Date`)
```

It will group your results by the date part of your datetime column `Date` and provide the sum of `quality` column for every date.

DATE function explanation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

SUM function explanation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Comment: Too help you @Alex_TNT : `DATE` function is explained here : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp

Comment: Am I doing something wrong or this outputs like 2015-05-13 3 2015-05-14 6 ?

Comment: I would expect 2015-05-13 -> 5 and 2015-05-14 -> 3 if the data in your question is the real one.

Answer (score 1):

The query you need is:

```
SELECT DATE(`date`) AS dateWhen, SUM(quantity) AS total
FROM downloads
GROUP BY dateWhen
```